Trying to retrieve data from a document in Firestore but it returns null when mapping to a Java object
Here is the code for the LessonGroup class:
public class LessonGroup implements Serializable {
    //properties
    private String studentId;
    private String lessonGroupId;
    private String courseId;
    private String dayOfWeek;
    private String startTimeOfDay;
    private String endTimeOfDay;
    private ArrayList<Lesson> lessons;
    private String firstLessonDate;
    private double boughtPrice;
    private int finishedLessonCount;
    private int totalLessonCount;
    private boolean hasPaid;

    public LessonGroup(){
        //public no-argument constructor needed for FireStore database
    }

    public LessonGroup(
            String studentId,
            String lessonGroupId,
            String courseId,
            String dayOfWeek,
            String startTimeOfDay,
            String endTimeOfDay,
            String firstLessonDate,
            double boughtPrice,
            int totalLessonCount){
        //initialise private properties

        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.lessonGroupId = lessonGroupId;
        this.courseId = courseId;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        this.startTimeOfDay = startTimeOfDay;
        this.endTimeOfDay = endTimeOfDay;
        this.lessons = new ArrayList<>();
        this.firstLessonDate = firstLessonDate;
        this.boughtPrice = boughtPrice;
        this.finishedLessonCount = 0;
        this.totalLessonCount = totalLessonCount;
        this.hasPaid = false;
    }
    //various accessor methods

    public String getCourseID() {
        Log.d("Is Null", String.valueOf(courseId==null));
        return this.courseId;
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public String getLessonGroupId() {
        return lessonGroupId;
    }
    public String getFirstLessonDate() {
        return firstLessonDate;
    }
    public String getDayOfWeek() {
        return dayOfWeek;
    }
    public String getStartTimeOfDay() {
        return startTimeOfDay;
    }
    public String getEndTimeOfDay() {
        return endTimeOfDay;
    }
    public double getBoughtPrice() {
        return boughtPrice;
    }
    public ArrayList<Lesson> getLessons() {
        return lessons;
    }
    public int getRemainingLessonCount() {
        return totalLessonCount - finishedLessonCount;
    }
    public int getFinishedLessonCount() {
        return finishedLessonCount;
    }
    public boolean getHasPaid() {
        return hasPaid;
    }
}

Here is the code for the method where I'm trying to call getCourseID():
private void getUserCoursesInfo(){
        ArrayList<LessonGroup> lessonGroups = studentUser.getAllLessonGroups();
        Log.d("StudentUser", "Is student null? " + String.valueOf(studentUser == null));
        Log.d("LessonGroup", "Is lessonGroup null? " + String.valueOf(lessonGroups == null));
        Log.d("LessonGroup", "Length " + String.valueOf(lessonGroups.size()));
        if(lessonGroups.size() == 0){
            return;
        }
        // for each lesson group in the student's lesson group array list
        for (LessonGroup lessonGroup : lessonGroups){
            Log.d("BoughtPrice", String.valueOf(lessonGroup.getBoughtPrice()));
            Log.d("ID", lessonGroup.getLessonGroupId());
            Log.d("StudentID", lessonGroup.getStudentId());

            // get the corresponding courseID attribute in the lessonGroup object
            String courseID = lessonGroup.getCourseID();
            Log.d("CourseID", "CourseID is null: " + String.valueOf((courseID == null)));
}

There are no errors when I upload the object to Firestore, however when I retrieve the data, I get null. Log.d() shows that the student user object is not null, the LessonGroup object is not null, and the other properties of the LessonGroup object is not null either. ONLY the courseID property is null, which it shouldn't be, because in Firestore it clearly has a non-null string value. Why is this happening?
In Firestore, courseID has a value of "ec08d467-19d8-4f0f-a6ce-53303227a351"
Android Studio Log displaying that courseID is null

Firestore database LessonGroup object document


The problem likely has to with your naming of courseID not matching JavaBeans standards.
Try changing the name of the course ID accessor method to getCourseId with a lowercase "d".  You should also change the name of the document field to courseId with a lowercase "d".  This will match the other fields and accessors where you also used lowercase that are working correctly, such as "studentId" and "lessonGroupId".
